# How big is an HDFS block?

Tags: hadoop, memory, hdfs, diskspace

I know its 64 MB, but what does MB mean here. Is it `64 * 1000000` or `64 * 1024 * 1024`? I need to know the exact value. I tried to google this but couldn't find any satisfying answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `64 * 1024 * 1024 = 67108864` (bytes).